# Is it possible to create a pdf with different page sizes in iOS - Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-graphics

I've done multiple times a pdf with all the pages at same size. Is it really possible to do a mixed sizes PDF on iOS? (like for example fixed width and multiple heights pages)

I'm finding a lot of discordant answers around, and very few data on platform-specific capabilities.

Comment: See `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo` or `CGPDFContextBeginPage`.

Comment: You should post an actual answer. It's fine to answer your own question if it may help others. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted in the wrong box :-)

Comment: No, post it as an answer. Don't put the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been as easy as just adding every page with a different mediabox.

```
// Start PDF file
NSMutableData *pdfFile = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
CGDataConsumerRef pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef)pdfFile);

CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(pdfConsumer, &mediaBox, NULL);

CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &mediaBox);

CGContextDrawImage(pdfContext, imageBox, [image CGImage]);
CGContextEndPage(pdfContext);

// Change mediabox

CGContextBeginPage(pdfContext, &mediaBox);
... etc....
CGContextEndPage(pdfContext);

// Close pdf

CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
CGDataConsumerRelease(pdfConsumer);
```